# AMDGPU new driver with support for 4.10 doesnt work

Tags: drivers, graphics, fan

AMD released a new driver for Ubuntu 16.04.3 and claims it supports 4.10 kernel now. I installed ubuntu again, then the amdgpu-pro driver. Same thing happens like before... The moment i press Ubuntu the screen turns off and the GPU fans spin at max speed. After 10 seconds i boot into Ubuntu but the fans dont stop... Did i do something wrong? I dont even know if the driver actually works. My GPU is Sapphire R9 380X 4GB

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Amethyst XT [Radeon R9 M295X Mac Edition / R9 380X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: f1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` and you'll see.

Comment: i see R9 380 as output but the problem is why i get that delayed boot and why the fans dont stop spinning.